# How can I change Windows auth for a method based on the parameters it is passed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows, authorization

Right now in my MVC application, I am using Windows Auth to restrict access to certain methods, like so:

```
   [Authorize(Roles = SystemRole.AppAdmin)]

    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        //Find group by id in db
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(Roles = SystemRole.AppAdmin)]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "id, otherParam")] Item thisItem)
        //Post changes to db
    }
```

I would like to have my code so that another AD group has limited admin rights to edit ONLY an item with a certain id (e.g. item 7), not allow them to access this method to try to edit other items.

I've tried Googling/searching Stack Overflow/reading Windows Auth documentation but must not be using good keywords, because I surely can't be the first person to want to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, what you want is to, based on their AD group, allow groups to make changes to specific groups.

If that is the case, see if there is an AD group that encompasses all these admins, have that be the authorize attribute

```
[Authorize(Roles = SystemRole.SomeBaseAdminGroup)]
```

Then fetch their claims and do a case switch based on the return into specific methods or specialized method calls. Since all roles are translated into Claims for Identity,

Comment: FDaniels, thanks for taking the time to answer. It looks like your comment was cut off mid-sentence?

The "group" referenced in the code isn't an AD group, it's a class within this application. I will make some edits to the question.

Comment: Whoops. Looking back at it, I understand more of your question, but it seems like Win's answer encompasses what I wanted to say. The combination should be enough for a solution. Though I went using the Identity route, but that may not work with your solution as it stands. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-create-a-custom-claim may help in creating the custom claims for the groups that you need.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of complex authorization is a bit tricky with *default* Windows Authentication.

You will need a hybrid approach in which your application stores users and their authorization in separate database.

[image]

Then add those authorization as claims when they sign-in. You can then apply *Authorize* attribute to action methods and controllers.

```
public void SignIn(User user, IList<string> roleNames)
{
   IList<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
   {
      new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, user.Id.ToString()),
      new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
      new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName),
      new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName),
   };

   foreach (string roleName in roleNames)
   {
      claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, roleName));
   }

   ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, AuthenticationType);

   IOwinContext context = _context.Request.GetOwinContext();
   IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = context.Authentication;

   authenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
}
```

I have a working sample application at [GitHub](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin). You can take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You are welcome. If this answers your question, please mark it as ***Answer***. It'll help the community. If you think GitHub project is useful, you are feel free to fork it. I also have another open source for [ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit).